# Encapsulation with C helper structs

Tags: c, struct, encapsulation

So say I am writing a linked list and in my header file I have :

```
struct Node {
    LIST_TYPE value;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

struct List{
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    void (*list_print_function)(void*);
};
```

But I do not want the client to be able to see the Node structure. Is the static modifier the correct way to do this? there is a not a lot of documentation on static structures.

Comment: What you mean with the **client**? The library user?

Comment: yes. so in my c file I have a helper function: 

static int print(LIST_TYPE v, List *list){
 (*(list->list_print_function))(v);
}

and this allows me to make it private to the c file itself.

Comment: since you do not want the user to see the struct definition,  place those definitions in the .c file in the library.  The .h file for that library should only have prototypes for the accessor functions  Like: addNode( list of fields)  delNode( nodeSelectorField ), modNode( selectorField, enum FieldSelector, newValue ), and the enum for field selector setNodeSelector( enum FieldSelector )  or some similar set of functions.  That way the user has no idea as to how the Node is implemented, etc

Answer (score 4):

What you want is an **opaque** structure, you can do that by declaring the `struct` in your header file which is called a **forward declaration** but only defining it in the implementation file, pretty much like when you give a function prototype but you don't give the definition.

You can then provide accessor functions to allow the library user to use the `struct`, an example

**data-type.h**

```
struct Struct;

void struct_set_value(struct Struct *struct, int value);
int struct_get_value(const struct Struct *const instance);
```

**data-type.c**

```
struct Struct
 {
    int value;
 };

void struct_set_value(struct Struct *instance, int value)
 {
    instance->value = value;    
 }

int struct_get_value(const struct Struct *const instance)
 {
    return instance->value;
 }
```

You can then, provide the `.h` file to the library user and the compiled object so they can link to it.

Comment: I believe you wanted to declare your setter function `void struct_set_value(struct Struct *instance, int value);`

Comment: Yes, of course. Fell free to edit if you see a copy paste issue like that or any other mistake.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you only use pointers to your `Node` you can hide the `struct` definition itself to the user of your library. The only thing that you'd have to place visible before your list definition is

```
typedef struct Node Node;
```

The `struct Node` itself is a forward declaration of your `struct` type. The `typedef` is needed to be able to use `Node` without the `struct`.